# AngularJS 1.2, angular-ui 0.6 modal not showing

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui

I am trying to get a login modal showing when I click on login.

I am using bootstrap3, angularJS1.2 and angular-ui0.6

When I click on login, the transparent background of the modal shows but the popup never appears. When I check in the console, I can actually see the code populated but never manages to display it.

I am guessing that it is a problem with 1.2 animation and 0.6 not being up to date but I am not sure (I actually reverted back to < 1.2 and I run into the same problem.

Any idea what may be happening?

Comment: I found some answers here : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/331

Seems to be a problem with bootstrap3.0 and a couple of things help like adding to your css :

.modal {display: block;height: 0;overflow: visible;}

Comment: That works bringing up the content, but sometimes with transparent background. Not nice :/.

Answer (score 5):

There is no support for Bootstrap 3 yet. This worked for me, however: [ngEkathuwa](http://plnkr.co/ebDtSMw6w0IZquaglEMe).

Answer (score 1):

AngularUI 0.6 does not work with BS3. I have been waiting for this particular fix to continue one of my projects. The modal view is specially broken. We have to wait till 0.7 comes out.

Comment: Angular UI 0.7 is out, but that didn't seem to include this fix.  I changed the content of `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.min.js` to this patch posted on the above mentioned github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/331 at http://phong.com/packages/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.min.js

Comment: Have you checked the 0.7 BS3 branch?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to build your own ui-bootstrap JS file, from a different branch, and use it instead (the angular-ui team is working on this separate branch to make it compatible with Bootstrap 3).

To build, just follow these steps (adapted from https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/331#issuecomment-25032867)

1. git clone https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap.git
2. cd bootstrap
3. git checkout origin/bootstrap3_bis2
4. npm install
5. grunt build

You'll find the new ui-bootstrap JS files in the ./dist/ folder.